# SQLI in Show. Is this possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails 5, I have a show page and on that I query @client with the following:

```
<% for client in @client.nearbys(500, :units => :km).where("(membertype_id = 3) OR (membertype_id = 4)")
```

.. The question is about the .where statement. Is the .where statement safe from SQL injections or other attacks? If not, what other ways would you write this?

Edit: I only have a show action in my routes and controller.

Comment: Do you use any attribute from client within your view where the value of the attribute is filled from an external service or a user you can't  trust? If yes how do you use this attribute within the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such logic in view kind'a wrong in a sense, that view layer is not responsible for querying data from DB - it's task to present data.

Move it to controller and then simply use `@clients` instance variable in view:

```
def show
  # equal to @client.nearbys(500, units: :km).where(membertype_id: [3,4])
  @client = @client.nearbys(500, :units => :km).where("(membertype_id = 3) OR (membertype_id = 4)")
end
```

This way there is no need to worry about safety.

## EDIT

As I said in comments, having it hardcoded (as you do) is as safe as having it hardcoded in model or controller - no difference.

Comment: I see your points, and I know this might not be the correct way. But circumstances are that I need to do it in the view. I have about 100+ statements of these type in my show view. If I put them in controller, it wont be a skinny controller. Should I put them in a scope and create a fat model instead? And then call the scope on @client in the view?Anyways, thanks for the help but I'm mostly interested in whether the statement in itself is safe. Is it?

Comment: @sneglefar i do not believe there must be 100+ statements, that could not be generalized into scope, for example. As to safeness - it is safe while it's hardcoded as in your example. Once you use params you will have to sanitize them.

Comment: Dont wanna de-rail my question, but the 100+ statements seem necessary, at least with my beginner-ruby-level, as I'm doing a related section, for 6 different categories with 9 or 10 different options of finding related clients - there really are a 100 different options with my setup. But.. Back on track: If I do this in my view and not in controller or a scope, is it then unsafe compared to if it was in my controller or in my model as a scope?

Comment: @sneglefar as I said, while you do not use user's input in your query, it is as safe as haiving it in model or controller.

Comment: Since I have so many statements, I just wanna know if its safe or not, so I can launch my app while I'll clean up the way the code is written later on and move it to the appropriate place.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sneglefar no probs :) Good luck!

Comment: Marked your answer as answered here, however if there is an overall consensus that the other answer is more correct, let me know and I'll change it to that. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @sneglefar  basically both answers pointed out that it's safe to have such query in view and both recommended to move code from view (to either model or controller or whatever). So I'm ok with you accepting mine - it appeared  first after all (if agreed that both answers are equally helpful) :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really seem to understand what SQL injection is in the first place:

[image: Credit xkcd.com]

SQL injection vulnerabilities occur when you take input from the user and use it construct a SQL query string.

```
User.where("foo = #{params[:bar]}")
```

So if the user passes `"'foo'); DROP TABLE 'users';--"` you're screwed.

```
User.where("foo = ?", params[:bar])
```

On the other hand does not have this vulnerability as the database replaces `?` with the values provided separately. Thus it would quote `"'foo'); DROP TABLE 'users'"` so that it is merely inserted as a value.

There is no SQLI vulnerability in:

```
@client.nearbys(500, :units => :km).where("(membertype_id = 3) OR (membertype_id = 4)")
```

Because you are not inserting any user input.

### But its still wrong.

In MVC you should avoid doing database queries in your views. Your views should just take data from the controller and use it to produce HTML.

Doing queries in your views leads to code duplication, poor DB optimisation etc.

Comment: max and @Andrey Deineko, you can't blame sneglefar for doing SQL within the view. I understand your point of view and would give the same recommendation, but only as a recommendation, because DHH says as Rails-Way (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktZLpjCanvg 7:19) that it is a good thingto execute SQL queries within the view, because it can be cached.

Comment: DHH says some pretty stupid stuff sometimes. Queries are cached on the db driver level by AR and in most cases when you use fragment caching the queries are actually not performed until you start to do something with the collection. Queriyng in the view willy-nilly is a really good way to create a wordpress style mess.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. However I do not understand how this is suggested to be in the controller, when there are so many (100) different (necessary) queries. It would indeed make it a fat controller. Isn't it better adviced to have them lay as a scope in the model then? My views are huge because of this, so I understand and appreciate your advice.

Comment: @max Thanks for clearing it up. I was of the impression that you could somehow still manipulate a request even though there is no form involved. HOWEVER, I have another form on the exact same page - But it has nothing to do with the abovementioned controller. It has a form_for(:contact, :url => contacts_path, method: :post) and leads to a create action and view from the contacts_controller, which is safeguarded with contacts_params. Is it possible to mess with the .where statement on the page via that form then?

Comment: You're mixing up requests and database queries. Totally different things.

Comment: Just use hashes instead of strings to create your queries and you don't really have to worry about SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks! Thought they could intertwine somehow. Checking out some more tutorials